# Can work be positive when looking at a negative charge experiencing a voltage?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, voltage, coulombs-law

Using V=W/q when q is negative and V is positive do we write the work as negative? In my question it says “How much work is done in moving 6 electrons through a potential difference of 2V?” My answer was -1.92x10^-18. Is this correct?

Comment: Work done by what? The electric field? An external force?

Comment: To reopen this question, please [edit] to focus on the conceptual part  in the title rather than the check-my-work part on the body.